# laravel 5.2 pagination error Method links does not exist

Tags: laravel, pagination

I am trying to paginate my results from a database using a Laravel 5.2.31 app, but the pagination isn't working.

When I use `{!! $users->links() !!}` in my view, I get an error 'Method links does not exist' .

The same thing happens when I use `{!! $users->render() !!}`

My Controller:

```
public function index() {
    $users= User::orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->paginate(4); 
    return view('home', ['users' => $users]); 
}
```

Any help?

Comment: View the contents of `$users` by doing `dd($users);` before calling the `view`.

Comment: as `linuxartisan` said dump the object and see if thats of type `LengthAwarePaginator`

Comment: Yes, it is of type LengthAwarePaginator. How can I render links?

Comment: Ok. Things worked. This is how : public function index(Request $request){
          $users= User::orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->paginate(4);
          $page = $request->get('page', 1); 
          $perPage = 4;
          $offset = ($page * $perPage) - $perPage;
          $usersarray = (array)$users;
          $paginator = new LengthAwarePaginator(array_slice($usersarray, $offset, $perPage, true), count($usersarray), 
          $perPage, $page, ['path' => $request->url(), 'query' => $request->query()]);
           return view('home', ['users' => $users,  'paginator' => $paginator]); }

Answer (score 0):

Could you please try this:

return \View::make('home')->with('users',$users);